# Strip out the 'n' \ new line out of the echo to a file

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, bash, echo

I have a bash script that pulls a bit of text from an external MySQL database. Most of the times it are 4 lines, each one on his own line. This text (in total) has to be placed into a file. The script now pulls the information from the MySQL database, puts it in a variable. Then I echo it in a file:

```
echo -ne $variable > file
```

The problem is that the 'n' gets also printed/echo'ed to the file. Like this:

```
here is sentence number 1
nthere is number 2
nals here comes number 3
nlast but not least number 4
```

somehow there is a kind of new-line that is printed and I need to have the text without the 'n'.

**EDIT 1 - copy of the Bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

DBHOST='xx.xxx.xx.xxxx'
DBUSER='xxxxxx'
DBPASS='xxxxxx'
DBNAME='xxxxxx'

mysql -N -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -h$DBHOST -D$DBNAME -e "SELECT id,vhost FROM test;" | while read id vhost;
do
echo -ne $vhost > vhost
done
```

For obvious reasons I removed the database details.

**EDIT 2 - I am using the following Bash and Ubuntu version:**

Ubuntu: 12.04.2
Bash: 4.2.25

Comment: _The script now pulls the information from the MySQL database, puts it in a variable._ --> How did you do this? Could you please show us your code?

Comment: I edited my post with the Bash script.

Comment: Why do you use `-e`, why no quotes? What is the content of the variables? `echo -n "$variable" | od -t c -t x1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first and biggest problem is that you need quotes around your variable.

```
echo -ne "$variable" > file
```

Then I would try omitting one or both of the `-e` and `-n`. Ideally, `printf` should be used instead of `echo` since it's more portable.

**Edit:**

Thanks for showing additional parts of your script which are essential in diagnosing the issue.

If the vhost field *may* contain the literal string "\n" (backslash-n *not* a newline) in its *contents* then you *must* use the `-r` option with `read` if you want to preserve the backslash. In fact, you should almost always use the `-r` anyway out of habit. By preserving the backslash, the `-e` option of `echo` will interpret the *literal* "\n" as the escape sequence which represents a newline and output a newline instead of an "n".

```
mysql -N -u$DBUSER -p"$DBPASS" -h$DBHOST -D$DBNAME -e "SELECT id,vhost FROM test;" | 
while read -r id vhost;
do
    echo -en "$vhost"
done > vhost
```

You can move the redirection to the end of the `while` loop to avoid repeatedly opening and closing the output file and overwriting the contents on each iteration. You can use the trailing pipe also as a line continuation character to aid in readability.

The habits I mentioned earlier, including always quoting a variable for output, should be well ingrained. They prevent unexpected behavior at inopportune times. Probably the best reference to use in learning these habits is [Greg Wooledge's BashFAQs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and other pages at that site.

Comment: I already tried that. Probably a habbit that I did not include the quotes. I tested it again a few minutes ago just to be sure, it still includes the 'n'.

Comment: It also makes no difference if I dont use the -e, dont use the -n or dont use them both. If I would like to use printf instead, what kind of command I would create?

Comment: pipe it into tr. echo "$variable" | tr -d '\n' > file

Comment: @JonaKoudijs: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have been playing around a little more but it still doesn't work. If I add the -r after 'read' I get '\n' after every line instead of 'n'.

Comment: @JonaKoudijs: If your fields contain "\n" then `echo -e` will interpret that as newlines. There is something you're not revealing. Please post an example of the output of the mysql `SELECT` statement which has not been passed through the `while` loop.

Comment: @JonaKoudijs: One other thing I wanted to mention is that you should use a my.conf file to contain your credentials rather than passing the password as a command line argument for security reasons. Otherwise somebody may be able to see the password using `ps`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thank you for reaction. It works now! I don't know exactly what I did that triggered it. Maybe I opened the wrong test file, because I did not really change anything. It is now as you said. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want to append (`>>`), not overwrite (`>`).
2. Are you sure that removing `-n` doesn't work?
3. Why not:

   `mysql -N -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -h$DBHOST -D$DBNAME -e "SELECT
   vhost FROM test;" > vhost`

Comment: I want to overwrite the file not append it.

I am 100% positive.

The script will be bigger en there a couple of other things that will get included in the loop part. So this way is better for me.